# Allow write permissions for .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, permissions

I've been running in circles with allowing my application to write to a folder on a shared network drive.

So far I have this:

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("myFolder/" + filename));
```

this successfully saves the file to

```
\\machineName\inetpub\wwwroot\myApp\myFolder
```

However, I am also trying to save the same file to a folder outside of the root folder on the path

```
\\machineName\myFolder
```

using:

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs("C:\\myFolder\\" + filename);
```

This returns an error of "Access Denied." So how do I go about allowing my application to write a file to \\machineName\myFolder? I have tried giving write permissions to IIS_IUSRS and NETWORK SERVICE to no avail. Should I create a user with privileges to write to the network drive and then use impersonation to use that user when writing to the drive?
Using IIS 7 with .NET 4 application.

Comment: have you tried running as admin? oh and I remember having to give permissions for a username that was specific to the application pool like IIS_[app pool name here]... don't forget to turn those permissions off

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work, you can try programatically changing permissions, as I [showed in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18623931/1810243).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your application's app pool, right click on it and choose **Advanced properties**. Check the **Identity** value under **Process model** settings group. Give this Identity permissions to write files in your folder.

If the value is `ApplcationPoolIdentity` than user name is `IIS APPPOOL\app_pool_name`.

Comment: Hey @Anri, thanks for the reply. When I attempt add a user/group name into the object names box, I get the "Name Not Found" dialog. I have been attempting to add IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Classic> I'm going to mess around with it a little bit more to see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Still unable to add permissions for IIS APPPOOL\app_pool_name. I have tried @MikeSmithDev solution with no luck as well. Can anyone provide further insight?

Comment: @user2596756 you realise `app_pool_name` is just a placeholder for your real application pool name, right?

Comment: yes. In my first comment I detail that I tried to add IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Classic

Comment: @user2596756 try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity